# "Object Required" error when trying to make a dynamic list class of TextBox

Tags: vba, object, dynamic, listbox, required

I'm fairly new at VBA and have been teaching it to myself so forgive me if this is a dumb question or if I mad a stupid mistake.

I am making a userform with a series of textboxes. Some of these textboxes will be required, some will be optional. I wanted to make an array to sort the required textboxes. I also thought this would be an opportunity to get experience making a dynamic array in VBA, so I decided to make a class to act as the array. However, when I try to open the userform, I get "Run-time error '424': Object Required".

I replicated the error is a much more simplified file so I could show you every line. Let me know what I am doing wrong. I researched people having similar problems but none of their solutions worked.

```
''''''''''''''''''Sheet1 code
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    UserForm1.Show
End Sub

''''''''''''''''''Userform code
Dim list1 As Class1

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Set list1 = New Class1

    list1.addTB (UserForm1.TextBox1)


End Sub

''''''''''''''''''Class code
Dim list() As MSForms.TextBox
Public size As Integer


Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    size = -1 ' list starts as empty


End Sub


Public Sub addTB(tb As MSForms.TextBox)
    size = size + 1
    ReDim Preserve list(size)
    Set list(size) = tb

End Sub

Public Function getTB(i As Integer)

    getTB = list(i)

End Function

Public Sub doNothing()


End Sub
```

Comment: `list1.addTB (UserForm1.TextBox1)` should be `list1.addTB UserForm1.TextBox1`. Call subs without parentheses. http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201608021344119140566

Comment: So simple -_-. Thanks a ton. After changing that and fixing a few other small errors, that fixed it up.

Comment: Yup, it's a frustrating quirk we have to deal with in vba. Luckily VB.Net saw the light and changed the syntax. More details here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/15/what-do-you-mean-cannot-use-parentheses/